# NOT FOUND http://localhost/~username/

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

I'm having the following problem when i try to access my projects on localhost from the Sites dir

Not Found

The requested localhost/~barrymcmahon/php_5_advanced/ was not found on this server.

I know apache is working because I get a response from localhost [It Works!] and I can curl it with headers using [curl --head localhost] and I get a 200 but when I try to use the projects in my sites folder I get the above error.

I have amended the httpd.conf file and the user/username.conf file to point to the correct dir.

I noticed this is in the browser header when i get the 404 [ dont know if it will help ]

Remote Address:[::1]:80

Is is possible that there is there a different format for the localhost path on yosemite os ?